# Difference Between Dates in the Same Dimension Using Tableau

Tags: function, tableau-api, calculated-field

I am working on a project for work that tracks the movement of customers within the starting stages of our funnel. There are three stages that I am looking at FT (First Touch), Engaged Lead, and MQL. For each contact ID, I want to know the number of days it took a lead to travel from FT, Engaged Lead, and MQL. Also, in some instances there are leads that jump from FT to MQL directly. The three stages are filters within a dimension titled "Stage". I only have one date dimension, titled "Transition Date". How do I create a calculated field that will give me the number of days it takes a lead to move through each stage?

Essentially, I would like to create a column between each stage to show me the number of days between each stage. This would be easy to do in excel, but this needs to be done in Tableau since we have a lot of data.

[image]

Comment: Can you post sample data so we don't need to guess at creating it?  Also, the ... under Engage in the first contact id means that there are multiple dates for that stage.  How did you want to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are getting data for every stage from a single date field you need to write separate calculated fields to extract date for a specific stage and then subtract.

FT Date

```
if stage = "FT"
then Trasition Date
end
```

MQL Date

```
if stage = "MQL"
then Trasition Date
end
```

Engaged Lead date

```
if stage = "Engaged Lead"
then Trasition Date
end
```

Now create one more calculated field to take difference.

```
DateDiff('day',[FT Date],[MQL Date])
```

Hope this helps